# Hive query on a bucketed table is slow

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, orc

I have 2 tables.
One is bucketed the other is not - other than that they are identical.
Both stored as orc and partitioned.
Querying the bucketed table on a given partition is much slower than querying its twin on the same partition.
Is it expected?
If not what can be the reasons for it?
If yes then should I conclude my only motivation to hold a bucketed table is for joins and sampling, and in this case hold 2 copies of the table - one bucketed and the other not (sounds wasteful)?

Comment: bucketing helps more in merge then filtering. Is slowness of bucketed table is for merge as well? Plus do reproduce this issue in your local Hadoop instance than in some enterprise Hadoop instance. Load on Hadoop servers could be a factor.

Comment: The slowness emerges in a query: "select colA,count(*) from my_table where ds="2015-09-18" group by colA" - which is indeed a 'flitering' query - but the "2015-09-18" is a partition on both tables so you would expect similar performance.

Comment: The load on the cluster is not an issue since I'm the only one running the jobs - when each of the queries is being run it is the only job running in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Currently HIVE does not support Bucketing related query optimization for columns in where clause. Bucketing will be beneficial during a join operation though. In the use case mentioned above Partition and ORC together with DATA stored in sorted order should give you the best response.